# "Zlib::GzipFile::CRCError crc error" when install gem packages

Tags: ruby, zlib, crc

[root@blanee local_cache]# gem install dm-core-0.9.11.gem 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::CRCError)
    invalid compressed data -- crc error

[root@blanee local_cache]# gem install ParseTree-3.0.5.gem 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::CRCError)
    invalid compressed data -- crc error

I have a lot gem packages to install, but some of them can be installed success, but some can't be. My OS is CentOS 5.

btw, the packages are good. because I installed them on another PC.

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Is a .gem just a .zip or a .gz file? You could try uncompressing them elsewhere and recompressing with zero compression in case that helps. Did you transfer the files to your CentOS machine intact, i.e. can you unzip -t them?

Comment: a .gem should not be .zip, no .gz either. 
yes, the files are ok, I packed them, use tar -czvf xx; and uncompress them on Centos. Files are good.
unzip -t xx.gem didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

be sure you have the latest version of rubygems installed. i've received this error in the past when i had an outdated version.

`gem update --system`